# Program does not terminate or comes back with an error for scanf function

Tags: c, function, scanf

This program does not terminate nor does it let me input any values, simply a black screen with no output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main()
{
    int size;
    printf("Enter number of elements in array:");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("\n%d\n", size);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: As for the first program, you do give it some input, and terminate that input with the Enter key?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `int scanf("%d\n", &size);`

Comment: i edited my question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: can't reproduce. Works perfectly well for me.

Comment: Since this works perfectly well for me, this might either be an issue with your terminal or not actually the code you're trying to use. Please double check whether this is actually the code you're compiling **and** running the program in a different shell doesn't work.

Comment: it should let me input a value with scanf

Comment: Note that if you enter blank lines, `scanf()` won't return; it will wait until you either type an integer or something that cannot possibly be an integer (a letter, etc).  If you want line-based input, don't use `scanf()`; use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` instead.  However, that's a wild guess about what's causing your program to 'not terminate'.

Comment: @Holmsler that works perfectly well. Really. See my comment of 15seconds ago.

Comment: Okay i guess my compiler is broken, thanks for the input!

Comment: @Holmsler that's really the most unlikely explanation.

Comment: well i run it and nothing comes up, when I try to run it again it just asks to terminate the running program

Comment: all points to your terminal being broken.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `newline` at the end of your prompt, like `printf("Enter number of elements in array:\n");` ?

Comment: No; it is most improbable that your compiler is broken.  Assume the compiler is perfect (it isn't, but it is safe for you to assume that until you know enough C not to run into this problem).  There is a problem with the way you are using it, or with the way you are running your test program.  How did you compile it?  How are you running it?  Is there an IDE getting in the way?  (Sorry, prejudices getting through there — but people more frequently have problems with such programs when using an IDE than when working at the command line.)

Comment: i have figured out the problem, my printf statment is working last, aka, after the scanf statment the printf("Enter number of elements in array:\n"); is working last

Comment: @Holmsler Blaming the compiler should be the absolute last thing you do.

Comment: @Holmsler that isn't how it's supposed to be. **Where are you running this program?** it seems like something is messing with the in- and output buffers of your program, something neither your compiler nor your code are accountable for.

Comment: although the printf enter the number statement is first in the code, it only prints after i enter a number into console

Comment: i am using gcc in windows with a plugin in notepad++

Comment: cmd /c gcc  -ansi -pedantic -Wall -W -Wconversion -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings testing.c -o testing.exe & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo. && echo Syntax errors were found during compiling.) ELSE (testing.exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're suffering from buffering. Add

```
    fflush(stdout);
```

after the `printf` line.

By default, if stdout goes to a terminal, it is line buffered, meaning output is only actually written when the buffer is full or when you output a newline (`\n`). Terminating the program (via `exit()` or returning from `main`) closes all open file handles and also forces a flush.

To make sure output is generated right then and there, call `fflush`.